# Strncpy add character

Tags: c, string, copy, strncpy

I need to modify a name of file passing by argument with adding "_out" and changing extension. So, first, I copy the name of old file without extension, like that

```
  char* arg1 = argv[1];

  char* var1 = NULL;
  var1 = malloc(strlen(arg1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy( var1, arg1 );
  var1[strlen(var1) - 1] = 'l';
  var1[strlen(var1) - 2] = 'm';
  var1[strlen(var1) - 3] = 'x';

  char* var1Out = NULL;
  var1Out = malloc((strlen(var1) + 4) * sizeof(char));

  strncpy( var1Out, var1, strlen(var1) - 4 ); //Marker


             .
             .
             .
```

But when I display **var1Out** with printf just after "//Marker", by passing "test.txt" by argument, I get : "test└" and finally my program return "test└_out.xml" at the end.
While when I modify marker line like this:

```
strncpy( var1Out, var1, strlen(var1) - 3 ); //Marker
```

it displays:

> test.

and with:

```
strncpy( var1Out, var1, strlen(var1) - 5 ); //Marker
```

it displays:

> tes

so it works perfectly.

Why does it adds a character when I use:

```
strncpy( var1Out, var1, strlen(var1) - 4 ); //Marker
```

?

Comment: Some time in the [**the documentation**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) for each of those string functions, and *exactly* what they do, would likely help. And I'm curious what you think your program does when the command line parameter passed is `"x"` (or any other string shorter than at least three chars). Be careful with your assumptions. they can come back to bite you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**strncopy**

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if
>   source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not
>   be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would
>   overflow).
>   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

That's why I had an additional character to my string, because it isn't considered like a null terminated C string.

So with adding in my code:

```
  var1Out[strlen(var1)- 4] = '\0';
```

It works.

Answer (score 4):

In the allocation for `var1` you miss the space for zero terminator. Use

```
malloc(strlen(arg1) + 1)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I was wrong, it doesn't work. After changing malloc(strlen(arg1)) to malloc(strlen(arg1) + 1), I have the same error. It's weird, because sometimes there isn't this error but sometimes there is. An idea please? thx

Comment: What is the command line argument you use when you see the error?

Comment: My program's name is "Test" and my file's name is "myFile.ext". In command I run "Test myFile.ext". But when I display var1Out, I get "myFile8" or "myFileM" or whatever aleatory char at the end of "myFile" instead of just "myfile".

Comment: Your last line `strncpy( var1Out, var1, strlen(var1) - 4 );` copies the specified number of chars from var1 to var1Out, but does not add zero terminator character at the end. So you end up with var1Out containing not zero-terminated string, and when you try to print it you will get random characters after the copied characters, or even crash.

Comment: Yes I found out it, justly I wrote a new answer ton explain how I solve this problem with this solution.